# Why are these carousel images adjusting height after a transition?

Tags: css, carousel

I have been messing around with a background carousel and the only issue I have is that when the images slide in, the height is adjusted in a  glitchy kind of manner. How do I fix this issue?

For reference, my webpage is [here](http://www.nestorconstruction.com).

Here is my carousel css:

```
.carousel-item,.active{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have this:

```
.img-slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and you should have this:

```
.img-slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

this makes the height consistent. `100vh` on the div that contains the image get's applied when the slide is already in the final position, that's why the image size "jumps".

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% height on both `carousel-inner` and `carousel-item`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your selectors are wrong for the way your HTML is setup.

Should be `.carousel-item` not `.carousel,.item`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height:100vh and put this css

```
   .carousel-item.active {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To solve your current page problem you can do following css code

```
.carousel-inner{
  height:100vh;
}
.carousel-item{
  height:100vh;
}
```